# SAS treatment of blanks interferes with regex rules

Tags: regex, string, csv, sas

I have a dataset which I need to clean using regex rules. These rules come from a file `regex_rules.csv` with columns `string_pattern` and `string_replace` and are applied using a combination of `prxparse` and `prxchange` as follows:

```
array a_rules{1:&NOBS} $200. _temporary_;
array a_rules_parsed{1:&num_rules} _temporary_;
if _n_ = 1 then
do i = 1 to &num_rules;
            a_rules{i} = cat("'s/",string_pattern,"/",string_replace,"/'");
    a_rules_parsed{i} = prxparse(cats('s/',string_pattern,'/',string_replace,'/','i'));
end
set work.dirty_strings;
    clean_string = dirty_string;
    do i = 1 to &num_rules;
    debug_string = cats("Executing prxchange(",a_rules{i},",",-1,",","'",clean_string,"'",")");
        put debug_string;
    clean_string = PRXCHANGE(a_rules_parsed{i},-1,clean_string);
end
```

Some rules specify replacing certain patterns with a single blank space, so the corresponding `string_replace` value in the file is a single blank space.

The issue I'm facing is that SAS never respects the single space, and instead replaces the matched `string_pattern` for these records with an empty string (the other rules are applied as expected).

To troubleshoot I executed the following:

```
proc sql;
   create table work.single_blanks as
      select
         string_pattern,
         string_replace,
   from work.regex_rules
      where string_replace = " ";
quit;
```

which yielded the expected records. I was confused to find that changing the where clause to
`where string_replace = ""` or
`where string_replace = "         "` gave identical results! (I've been using sas for a while but I guess this behavior has gone unnoticed until now). Consequently, I could not determine whether SAS is neglecting to properly read in the file and retain the single blank, or whether one of the prx functions is failing to properly handle the single blank.

I can think of "hacky" work-arounds, but I'd rather understand what I'm doing wrong here and what the correct solution should be.

**EDIT 1:**

Here is a rule from the file and how I'd expect it to act on an example input value:

```
string_pattern, string_replace  
"(#|,|/|')", " "
```

running the code above on the input string `dirty_string = "10,120 DIRTY DRIVE";` does not produce the expected output of "10 120 DIRTY DRIVE" but rather "10120 DIRTY DRIVE".

**EDIT 2**

In addition to not respecting single spaces, leading and trailing spaces do not seem to be respected. For example, for a file with the rules

```
string_pattern, string_replace  
"\\bDR(\\.|\\b)", "DRIVE "
"\\bS(\\.|\\b)?W(\\.|\\b)", " SOUTH WEST"
```

running the code above on the input string `dirty_string = "10120 DIRTY DR.SW.";` does not produce the expected output of "10120 DIRTY DRIVE SOUTH WEST" but rather "10120 DIRTY DRIVESW.". This is because the space at the end of the first `string_replace` value gets lost, meaning there is no word boundary at the beginning of the second `string_pattern` to be matched.

Comment: Why did you ask SAS to ignore the blank values by using the CATS() function if you didn't want it to ignore the blank values?

Comment: Please show some of the values for the input variables and what values you want to generate from them.  Without details of what you are doing we are just going to have to make guesses about what is happening and what you want to happen.

Comment: The main reason is that replacing `cats` with `cat` yields several errors (too long to paste in a comment but I can add to the post if needed), and still doesn't seem to preserve the blanks when put to the log. If I could get rid of those errors I would revert but unfortunately I can't. It is helpful though to focus there as I thought this may be the culprit

Comment: Are you expecting `string_replace = "DRIVE ";` to generate something different than `string_replace = "DRIVE";`  ?  If so you will need store the fact that the first value is 6 characters long and the second only 5 somewhere else.

Comment: Also the PUT statement will normally remove leading and trailing spaces. Unless you use the `$CHAR` or `$VARYING` format in your PUT statement.

Comment: Thanks @Tom. The `string_replace = "DRIVE ";` line in my first edit was just to show how the rules are stored in the file. I don't actually enter them in code. I've modified the edit to clarify this, and moved it to **edit 2** so that the new **edit 1** can more directly meet your request for an example of a single space not being respected

Comment: Your main problem in your example is a poor regular expression.  This `(#|,|/|')` needs to have the `/` escaped.  Try `(#|,|\/|')` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SAS stores character variables as fixed length strings that are padded with spaces. As a consequence string comparisons ignore trailing spaces.  So `x=' '` and `x='      '` are the same test.

The `CATS()` will remove all of the leading and trailing spaces, so empty strings will generate nothing at all. It sounds like you want to treat an empty string as a single space.  The TRIM() function will return a single space for an empty string.  So perhaps you just want to change this:

```
cats('s/',string_pattern,'/',string_replace,'/','i')
```

into

```
cat('s/',trim(string_pattern),'/',trim(string_replace),'/','i')
```

Here is a working code (with a fixed string_pattern) of your example data:

```
data test;
   length string_pattern string_replace dirty_string expect 
          clean_string regex $200
   ;
   infile cards dsd truncover;
   input  string_pattern string_replace dirty_string expect;
   regex= cat('s/',trim(string_pattern),'/',trim(string_replace),'/i') ;
   regex_id = prxparse(trim(regex));
   clean_string = prxchange(regex_id,-1,trim(dirty_string));
   if clean_string=expect then put 'GOOD'; else put 'BAD';
   *put (_character_) (=$quote./);
cards4;
"(#|,|\/|')", " ","10,120 DIRTY DRIVE","10 120 DIRTY DRIVE"
;;;;
```

If any of your values have significant trailing spaces then you will need to store the data differently.  You could for example quote the values:

```
string_replace = "'DRIVE '";   
...
cat('s/',dequote(string_pattern),'/',dequote(string_replace),'/','i')
```

If you only add quotes around values that need them then you will need to include the TRIM() function calls.

```
cat('s/',dequote(trim(string_pattern)),'/',dequote(trim(string_replace)),'/','i')
```

Or store the string lengths into separate numeric fields.

```
cat('s/',substrn(string_pattern,1,len1),'/',substrn(string_replace,1,len2),'/','i')
```

And note that if any of your original character strings had either significant leading or trailing spaces they would have been eliminated by reading the data from a CSV file.

Comment: Sorry it took so long to get back to you, but my sas environment has been down. Firstly, I want to really thank you for spending so much time to give a thoughtful response. Using  `cat` + `trim` did help with the case of a single blank, but in a case like "DRIVE " it still drops the blank. So the recommendation for such replacement strings is to store them quoted, then dequote in SAS, is that correct?

Comment: Either store something in the text to indicate the boundaries of what you want to use. Or store the length in a separate field.

Comment: Okay, so I had trouble getting my infile to read strings like `'DRIVE '` and retain the single quotes, so I decided to use ` in place of ' and then convert back using `tranwrd` after reading in the file. Then I used your dequote approach and it worked. Somewhat "hacky" I'd say but I'll leave well enough alone and proceed to other issues!

Once again, thanks a hundred for your assistance here. Really appreciate it

Comment: SAS will treat both single quotes and double quotes as quoting when reading a delimited file using DSD option.  So you would need to construct the CSV file to have quotes around the quoted values. `field1,"'field2    '",filed3` or `field1,'"field2    "',filed3`  or  `field1,"""field2    """,filed3`